# Rewriting ID to slash in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, hyperlink

Can someone help me to rewrite the url id from www.website.com/script/?id=3 to www.website.com/script/3/

It mean that is want to remove the id=?id.

Here is my .htaccess file code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^script/([^/\.]+)/?$ script.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Rule seems to be fine. What is the exact problem? Do you have your `AllowOverride` set, so Apache would read the `.htaccess` file? PS. It rewrites `www.website.com/script/3/` to `www.website.com/script/?id=3`, not `www.website.com/script/?id=3` to `www.website.com/script/3/`

Comment: The AllowOVerride is set. The .htaccess file is working. I recently tried to delete `.php` from the URL and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteRule ^script/(.*)$    script.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: that will trigger the last `/` from `www.website.com/script/3/` request

Comment: Not working. I get: The requested URL /script/321022ae47.php was not found on this server.. The page works when I enter: script?id=321022ae47

Comment: okay @the_boy_za remove `[L]` from my answer and your good to go `/script/321022ae47` or `/script/321022ae47/` either will work

Comment: Still not working. I still get the message that the URL is not correct. The page `script/?id=321022ae47` is still online.

Comment: @the_boy_za i have tested the answer i gave you and it worked perfect. `yoursite.com/script/` also `yoursite.com/script/321022ae47` i dont see any issues. find out whats wrong with your server or some thing is interfering with that command . or may be you have an active `script` folder in your project. you must not have any folder named `script`

Comment: I also tried it out with other pages that are in other folders. I get a internal server error when i try to load: '/script/321022ae47'

Answer (score 0):

You need to reorder your rules  placing specific Rewrite at top . Replace your htaccess contents with the following :

```
RewriteEngine on
#rewrite /script/foobar to /script.php?id=foobar
RewriteRule ^script/([^/\.]+)/?$ script.php?id=$1 [L]
#remove .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: I have reordered the rules. `.php` is hidden but the URL /script/321022ae47 is not accessible. `/script?id=321022ae47` is still working